# External users cannot able to sign in with azure active directory v2 connection?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I had a microsoft bot application that uses the azure active directory v2 connection for sign in the users to the application. But it does not allow the external or other users to sign in to the application. I know the one way is that adding the guest user to the azure active directory so that it will allow. But I need to know is there other way to allow any users to sign in with azure active directory without adding them as a guest user.

The below messages is displayed when other users try to sign with the azure active directory v2 connectivity.

**The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.**

Comment: Make your application multi-tenant?

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks. Now I developed a bot with microsoft bot framework with node.js. I created the web app bot, in that I created a azure active directory connection to sign in the users. But you said "Make your application multi-tenant?" it does not made me clear. Please help

Comment: I haven't worked with Bot framework so I may be wrong here but if you can make your Azure AD application multi-tenant, then users from other Azure AD can sign into your application. That's what I meant by making your application multi-tenant.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks. Is only azure account is enough to sign in with any multi-tenant application or I need to have separate azure AD?

Comment: You don't need a separate Azure AD. In your Azure AD, locate the application and make that multi-tenant. That should do the trick I think.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks for your response, will try according to your answer.

Comment: Do try it out. I would be curious to know the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I need to know is there other way to allow any users to sign in
>   with azure active directory without adding them as a guest user.

[Multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) will only allow the accounts in any organizational directory to login. If you want accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts to login, you should use [Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison) and [change your account type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest) to the third one.
[image]

Also,remember to use the **Common** endpoint to login in.

**Update:**

Go to azure portal->click Azure Active Directory->choose your application->click Authentication

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I followed this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common but I cannot able to follow the document. Can you please tell how my change my app as a multi-tenant one.

Comment: Thanks Tony Ju. I already changed this but there is not no change. still continue with same error. It is error message "AADSTS50020: User account 'xxx@stems.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/a8esdf1-43e8-4c3c-96be-344s324cf6887/' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application '4d6da-f9a8-4ewr845-cf4e7adfa421'(sample application) tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account."

Comment: @Prakash Did you use the Common endpoint to login in? Like https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?

Comment: @Prakash https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common   Update your code to send requests to /common

Comment: Thanks Tony Ju. Where I need to change my endpoint. I did not find any endpoint in my application . It only has a redirect URI. my redirect URI is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193366/discussion-between-tony-ju-and-prakash).

Comment: I did not use any endpoint in my code. I just specified the connection name which I configured in azure active directory in oauth connection settings.

Comment: I got another problem regarding sign in through bot azure AD connection..As like you said I made the azure AD connection to multi tenant.that also allows the other organization account to login..but for the further proceedings the sign in window doesn't shows any other accounts to login..It just shows an empty screen when i click the sign in button and it automatically redirects to the last sign in account...But when I made the authentication as single tenant one the sign in window shows to select one from multiple accounts

Comment: @Prakash It is strange. I didn't reproduce this issue on my side.

Comment: Actually before a month we had a conversion with azure multi-tenant connection. There my redirect url is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect and what may be logout url. This is the problem for me when logout then the user was not properly logout from the application. So only from the next time it does not ask me the list of accounts to select. So what may be logout url?